# Ajax wait for Animation to complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, animation, wait

I know this topic had been discussed earlier on stackoverflow. But all the results wont help to solve my problem.

I use the "form" jQuery plugin like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({
        data: { Ajax: '1' },
        beforeSubmit:  beforeSEND,  // pre-submit callback
        success:       resultHANDLE  // post-submit callback
        });
    });

function beforeSEND () {
    $('#myForm').fadeTo(0, 0.5);
    $("textarea").addClass('loading');
    $("textarea").animate({backgroundPositionX: 0},1500});  
}

function resultHANDLE (responseText) {
    // Do somethig with the result
}
```

In the beforeSEND function a background img is attached to the textarea and is moving from left to right. Kinda like a progress bar.

My problem now: The Ajax request fires and the results are handled, no matter the animation has finished or not.
How can I force JavaScript to wait for the animation to finish and send AFTER it the request?

Many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "complete" callback from the various animation functions :

> complete Type: Function() A function to call once the animation is
>   complete

You could do something like this :

```
$('#myForm').fadeTo(0, 0.5, function() { 
    $("textarea").addClass('loading');
    $("textarea").animate({backgroundPositionX: 0}, 1500, function() {
       $('#myForm').ajaxForm({
        data: {Ajax:'1'},
        success:       resultHANDLE
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Good for me, the jQuery "Form" Plugin, offers 2 main functions. One is "AjaxForm" and the second (which i used) is "AjaxSubmit"
AjaxSubmit fires a Ajax-Request.
So I play the animation with a click handler on the submit button. When the animation is finished, I fire the form with AjaxSubmit.
Ofc I needed to alter the type=submit to type=button (so the form dont sends it self 2 times.)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/):

```
  function setAjaxForm() {

      $('#myForm').ajaxForm({
          data: { Ajax: '1' },
          beforeSubmit: beforeSEND,  // pre-submit callback
          success: resultHANDLE,  // post-submit callback
      });
  }

  $('#myForm').fadeTo(0, 0.5).promise().done(function() {

    $("textarea")
      .addClass('loading')
      .animate({backgroundPositionX: 0},1500)
      .promise().done(setAjaxForm);

  });
```